# Streaming Incoming video calls in Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-streaming

I am looking for a way to stream incoming video calls(via whatsapp, fb, insta, skype etc.) in my flutter app or in mobile background without using any third party tool. My aim is to store it in database for processing.

Kindly suggest any pointers in this regards.

Thanks,
Shalini